# How do you overwrite a unix file in Powershell?

Tags: unix, powershell

How do you overwrite a unix file in Powershell? That is on a UNIX server being accessed by FTP form a SQL server.

I am going to creat a job in job agent.

Currently ‘myfile.txt’ contains a Y

I want it to overwrite and contain a N

Comment: an file on a unix server not the local sql server

Comment: @BlackBear: http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell

Comment: You need to mention your method of access to 'the unix file' (presumably sftp, ftp, scp, ... ?)

Comment: It will be FTP where do I put the connection String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

echo N > myfile.txt? – BlackBear answered it.